# Use Python libraries to extract the main topic of a text

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk

I want to get the main topic (or a set of main topics) of a text using Python.

So far, I looked at the APIs of `nltk` and `scikit-learn` to see if there is such a method.
However, the best thing I found was this explanation http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html, which doesn't mention how to extract the main topic.

Is there any Python library which offers this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html) bundled with `scikit-learn`, but be advised that there is no 'main topic' of a text - a sentence can be about multiple topics.

[Here](http://blog.echen.me/2011/08/22/introduction-to-latent-dirichlet-allocation/) is a good introduction to LDA. LDA models documents as mixtures of a topic distribution from which words are generated with a certain probability. There is no need to specify beforehand the sorts of topics one might encounter - LDA will do it automatically for you.

Quoting from the blog post I linked to:

> In more detail, LDA represents documents as mixtures of topics that spit out words with certain probabilities. It assumes that documents are
> produced in the following fashion: when writing each document, you
>
> - Decide on the number of words N the document will have (say, according
>   to a Poisson distribution).
> - Choose a topic mixture for the document (according to a Dirichlet distribution over a fixed set of K topics).For example, assuming that we have the two food and cute animal topics above, you might choose the document to consist of 1/3 food and 2/3
>   cute animals.
> - Generate each word w_i in the document by:
> - - First picking
>     a topic (according to the multinomial distribution that you sampled
>     above; for example, you might pick the food topic with 1/3 probability
>     and the cute animals topic with 2/3 probability).
> - - Using the topic to
>     generate the word itself (according to the topic’s multinomial
>     distribution). For example, if we selected the food topic, we might
>     generate the word “broccoli” with 30% probability, “bananas” with 15%
>     probability, and so on.
>
> Assuming this generative model for a
> collection of documents, LDA then tries to backtrack from the
> documents to find a set of topics that are likely to have generated
> the collection.